# How to use array_concat with float column and array column

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I want to create an array that combines an array column with a float column into one array

I have tried `array_concat(array_column, float_column)` but get the error:

> Error: The argument to ARRAY_CONCAT (or ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG) must be an array type but was DOUBLE at [2:29]

With a string column (that contained one word in each row) I converted it to an array using split on " " as a trick to create an array and then use array_concat, but I can't do that with a float column.

I basically want to convert a float column to an array type so I can use Array_concat with other arrays.

```
SELECT Product_ID, array_concat(split(Product_Name , ' '), price) as description
FROM table
```

I want a single array that combines my array column with the single element in my non-array float column.

Comment: I found a trick to cast the price to a string, concatenate with the product_name with a space in between, then split, however, i think it should be easier than this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want ?

```
WITH Raw AS (
  select "product1_name" AS a, 2.0 AS b
  union all
  select "product2_name", 3.0
)

select
  [a, CAST(b AS STRING)]
FROM
  Raw
```

-----Reply-----

Combine array annotation and `ARRAY_CONCAT` function should work

```
WITH Raw AS (
  select ["a", "b", "c"] AS a, 2.0 AS b
  union all
  select ["b", "c"], 3.0
)

select
  ARRAY_CONCAT(a, [CAST(b AS STRING)])
FROM
  Raw
```

Comment: No, in your case you're creating an array out of a string type and a float type column. What I want is an array of array type and float type column. Basically, append the single float element to the array in the array column. If I use your method, I end up with a nested array which is not supported. for example [['a','b','c'],3.0], but what I want is ['a','b','c',3.0] (if arrays only support a single data type, then  ['a','b','c','£3'] works too

Comment: Got it, there is a revised answer according to your condition. Please have a look